# Argument of type '{ status: string; DetailsAnnouncementListItemState: { items: IListItem[]; columns: undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns

I have the following error, and below I will try to explain what I am trying to accomplish:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ status: string; DetailsAnnouncementListItemState: { items: IListItem[]; columns: undefined[]; }...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<IFactoryMethodState, "status" | "DetailsAnnouncementListItemState">'.
  Types of property 'DetailsAnnouncementListItemState' are incompatible.
    Type '{ items: IListItem[]; columns: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState'.
      Types of property 'items' are incompatible.
        Type 'IListItem[]' is not assignable to type 'IAnnouncementListItem[]'.
          Type 'IListItem' is not assignable to type 'IAnnouncementListItem'.
            Property 'announcementBody' is missing in type 'IListItem'.
```

I have a base interface and extended interfaces that represent list items in sharepoint depending on the list, a normal list has id, title, createdby, createddate, etc, other lists inherit the same fields, but add additional fields, so my design is like this:

```
export  interface IListItem {
    [key: string]: any;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    modified: Date;
    created: Date;
    modifiedby: string;
    createdby: string;    
}


import {IListItem} from './IListItem';

export interface  INewsListItem extends IListItem {
    newsheader: string;
    newsbody: string;
    expiryDate: Date;
}

import {IListItem} from './IListItem';

export interface IDirectoryListItem extends IListItem {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        mobileNumber: string;
        internalNumber: string;  
}

import {IListItem} from './IListItem';

export interface  IAnnouncementListItem extends IListItem {
    announcementBody: string;
    expiryDate: Date;  
}
```

Now, I have a factory method design pattern like this:

```
import { IListItem } from './models/IListItem';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
export  interface IFactory{
    getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[];
}

import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { IWebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { IListItem} from './models/IListItem';
import { IFactory } from './IFactory';
import { INewsListItem } from './models/INewsListItem';
import { IDirectoryListItem } from './models/IDirectoryListItem';
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from './models/IAnnouncementListItem';

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory{   
    getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[] {
        switch(listName) {
            case 'List':
                let items: IListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                    'odata-version': ''
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }): void => {
                    items= response.value;
                });
                return items;
            case 'News':
                let newsitems: INewsListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                    'odata-version': ''
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: INewsListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: INewsListItem[] }): void => {
                    newsitems= response.value;
                });
                return newsitems;
            case 'Announcements':
                let announcementitems: IAnnouncementListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                    'odata-version': ''
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: IAnnouncementListItem[] }): void => {
                    announcementitems= response.value;
                });
                return announcementitems;
            case 'Directory':
                let directoryitems: IDirectoryListItem[];
                requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                    'odata-version': ''
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IDirectoryListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((response: { value: IDirectoryListItem[] }): void => {
                    items= response.value;
                });
                return directoryitems;
            default:
                return null;
        }
      }
}
```

so far so god, however on my react component when I try to use it:

```
 private readItems(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: 'Loading all items...'
    });
    let factory = new  ListItemFactory();

    //Here its where we actually use the pattern to make our coding easier.
    switch(this.props.listName)
    {
      case "List":
        let listItems  = factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName);  
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${listItems.length} items`,
          DetailsListItemState : {
            items: listItems,
            columns: [
            ]
          }
        });      
        break;
      case "Announcements":
        let announcementlistItems  = factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName);  
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${listItems.length} items`,
          DetailsAnnouncementListItemState : {
            items: announcementlistItems,
            columns: []
          }
        });          
        break;
      case "News":
        let newsFactory = new  NewsListItemFactory();
        let newsListItems  = newsFactory._getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName);  
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${listItems.length} items`,
          DetailsNewsListItemState : {
            items: newsListItems,
            columns: []
          }
        });      
        break;
      case "Directory":
        let directoryFactory = new  DirectoryListItemFactory();
        let directoryListItems  = directoryFactory._getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName);  
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${listItems.length} items`,
          DetailsDirectoryListItemState : {
            items: directoryListItems,
            columns: []
          }
        });   
        break;
      default : 
        break;
    }    
  }
```

This is the place where I get the exception, the first switch case works fine, the second one doesnt, and I understand whats happening, getitems return ListItem[], but I am trying to assign the value to an AnnouncementListItem[]

However I am not sure how to fix it, as you could see the newslisitem extends ListItem, and I want to make this solution as generic as possible

Update,

Forgot this file

```
import { IListItem } from './models/IListItem';
import { INewsListItem } from './models/INewsListItem';
import { IDirectoryListItem } from './models/IDirectoryListItem';
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from './models/IAnnouncementListItem';
import {
  IColumn
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList';

export interface IFactoryMethodState{
  type: string;
  status: string;
  DetailsListItemState: IDetailsListItemState;
  DetailsNewsListItemState: IDetailsNewsListItemState;
  DetailsDirectoryListItemState : IDetailsDirectoryListItemState;
  DetailsAnnouncementListItemState : IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState;
}

export interface IDetailsListItemState {
  columns: IColumn[];
  items: IListItem[];
}

export interface IDetailsNewsListItemState {
  columns: IColumn[];
  items: INewsListItem[];
}

export interface IDetailsDirectoryListItemState {
  columns: IColumn[];
  items: IDirectoryListItem[];
}

export interface IDetailsAnnouncementListItemState {
  columns: IColumn[];
  items: IAnnouncementListItem[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I am only going to talk about `IAnnouncementListItem` but you can use the same analysis for each of your subtypes.

---

The error is correctly telling you that the compiler has no way to verify that `factory.getItems()` returns an array of `IAnnouncementListItem`.  As you said, `IAnnouncementListItem` *extends* `IListItem`, which means that every `IAnnouncementListItem` is an `IListItem`, but *not every `IListItem` is an `IAnnouncementListItem`*.  So it is warning you that you are doing something unsafe by treating an array of `IListItem` as an array of `IAnnouncementListItem`.

There are multiple ways to deal with it:

---

### Type Assertions

One is to just tell the compiler that you know what you're doing and that it shouldn't worry, by asserting that the return value of `factory.getItems()` is the right type.

```
let announcementlistItems  = factory.getItems(
  this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName
) as IAnnouncementListItem[];
```

This silences the compiler, but you lose the benefit of the compiler's type checking.

---

### Runtime type guards

Another way is to take the result from `getItems()` and perform a runtime check to see if the return value is actually an array of `IAnnouncementListItem[]`.  Here's an example:

```
function isArrayOfIAnnouncementListItem(arr: IListItem[]): arr is IAnnouncementListItem[] {
  return arr.every(listItem => 'announcementBody' in listItem);
}
```

And then

```
let announcementlistItems  = factory.getItems(
  this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName
);
if (!isArrayOfIAnnouncementListItem(announcementListItems)) {
  throw new Error("Wrong Type or Something");
}
// now announcementListItems is known to be IAnnouncementListItem[]
```

This will make the compiler happy.  It's safer than a bare assertion, but you're still doing runtime checks.  If someone else implemented `getItems()`, this might be the best you could do.  But since *you're* implementing it, you can actually make `getItems()` itself safer:

---

### Overload signature

Probably the best way to deal with it is to change the signature of `getItems()` so that it knows that the `listName` parameter affects the output type.  This can be done using [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
// overloads
getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: "Announcements"): IAnnouncementListItem[];
// put other overloads for each allowable type here

// implementation
getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): IListItem[] | null; { // .. implementation
```

(You can get this behavior with generics instead of overloads if you want; more info available upon request)

Now when you call `getItems()` you will be restricted to using a `listName` from the set of acceptable values, and the return type will be narrowed for you.

---

So, you can do any of those if you want.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!